# Find Duplicates in R based on multiple characters

Tags: r, duplicates

I can't seem to remember how to code this properly in R -

if I want to remove duplicates within a csv file based on multiple entries - first name and last name that are stored in separate columns

Then I can code: file[(duplicated(file$First.Name),]
but that only looks at the first name, I want it to look at the last same simultaneously.

If this is my starting file:

```
    Steve Jones
    Eric Brown
    Sally Edwards
    Steve Jones
    Eric Davis
```

I want the output to be

```
    Steve Jones
    Eric Brown
    Sally Edwards
    Eric Davis
```

Only removing names of first and last name matching.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are the first names and last names stored as separate columns?

Comment: "Stave" and "Steve" are not the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
file[!duplicated(file[c("First.Name", "Last.Name")]), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single column, use `sub` to remove the substring (i.e. first name) followed by space, get the logical vector (`!duplicated(..`) based on that to subset the rows of the dataset.

```
df1[!duplicated(sub("\\w+\\s+", "", df1$Col1)),,drop=FALSE]
#           Col1
#1   Steve Jones
#2    Eric Brown
#3 Sally Edwards
#5    Eric Davis
```

---

If it is based on two columns and the dataset have two columns, just do `duplicated` directly on the dataset to get the logical vector, negate it and subset the rows.

```
df1[!duplicated(df1), , drop=FALSE]
#  first.name second.name
#1      Steve       Jones
#2       Eric       Brown
#3      Sally     Edwards
#5       Eric       Davis
```

Comment: was going to do this `!duplicated(gsub('.* ', '', d2$V1))` :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for better performance (using data.table assuming First Name and Last Name are stored in separate columns):

```
> df <- read.table(text = 'Steve Jones
+     Eric Brown
+     Sally Edwards
+     Steve Jones
+     Eric Davis')

> colnames(df) <- c("First.Name","Last.Name")
> df
  First.Name Last.Name
1      Steve     Jones
2       Eric     Brown
3      Sally   Edwards
4      Steve     Jones
5       Eric     Davis
```

Here is where `data.table` specific code begins

```
> dt <- setDT(df)
> unique(dt,by=c('First.Name','Last.Name'))
   First.Name Last.Name
1:      Steve     Jones
2:       Eric     Brown
3:      Sally   Edwards
4:       Eric     Davis
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
!duplicated(paste(File$First.Name,File$Last.Name))
```